# Th(A) is omega-categorical iff Th(A; a) is omega-categorical.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Consider the following theorem:

[image: Proof that Th(A) is omega-categorical iff Th(A; a) is omega-categorical.]

I do not understand how to arrive at the claim underlined in red in the picture. Why is that true?

We use the following definition of type:

[image: Definition of type]

Comment: It's an argument using the compactness theorem: you already know that the type is conisistent with the theory of $A$. Then you use compactness to show that the type is conisistent with the elementary diagram of $A$. But this is a basic fact about types that should be proven right after the definition. What book or notes are you reading?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Maybe I understand how to prove it already. The lecture notes prove "$p$ is finitely satisfiable in $M$ if and only if $p$ is realized in some elementary extension of $M$." Because $p$ is consistent with the complete theory $\text{Th(A)}$ it must be that for any $\varphi_1(\bar{x}), \cdots, \varphi_n(\bar{x})$ in $p$ we have $A \models \exists \bar{x} (\varphi_1(\bar{x}), \cdots, \varphi_n(\bar{x}))$.

Comment: Exactly! Being consistent with the theory of $A$ is equivalent to being finitely satisfiable in $A$.

Comment: The other direction of my claim about equivalence?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Ok, yes, that's right - it's a direct application of compactness. In the interest of having this question answered, and since I've done little more here than point you in the right direction, I suggest you summarize what you've learned as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Excellent idea. I will as soon as I have the time! Thanks, again!